# OLE Word. Направление текста в таблице справа налево для иврита

Tags: c++, c++builder

Как сделать для ячейки таблицы направление текста справа налево для иврита?

Comment: Укажите в вопросе какая версия C++Builder используется, как называется компонент, и т.д. попробуйте привести [mcve].

Comment: C++ Builder 2009. Код предоставить не могу.